# Nuxt SPA dynamic routes based on Firebase Firestore data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, routes, nuxt.js

So I want to have a nuxt site hosted on Netlify where there's a child route whos slug is a firebase firestore document id.

Example:

```
https://www.example.com/users/steve
```

(where "steve" is the documentid)

So when the route is hit I would need to query firebase to see if it exists, and if not I would have to return a 404. Is this even possible?  I can do it easy in .net or php, but I'm very unsure of a SPA.

Specifically what should I be looking for in the docs, if I can do this?

Comment: Hello there, I'm facing the exact problem as you, having a SPA Nuxt app hosted on Netlify, where I need to display data from Firebase on dynamic routes. I would really appreciate if you can share your solutions. Is this possible with the given stack of technologies ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to implement an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that you would call like a REST API, sending an HTTP GET request to the functions endpoint.

As explained in the doc "Used as arguments for `onRequest()`, the Request object gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request sent by the client".

So you Cloud Function would look like:

```
exports.getUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // get the value of the user by parsing the url
  const baseUrl = req.baseUrl;
  //Extract the user from baseUrl
  const user = ....

 //query the Firestore database
 admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user).get()
 .then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        res.status(404).end();
    }

});
```

---

See the [get started page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) and the [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series) for more info on Cloud Functions.

Note that you can [connect an HTTP function to Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#connecting_http_functions_to), in such a way that "requests on your Firebase Hosting site can be proxied to specific HTTP functions".

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the exact problem. I want to try out your answer, but how can I write firebase function if my app is hosted on Netlify ?